# Return a list of elements that are NOT in two previous lists

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have 2 lists of IDs and I need to return a list with the products that aren't in any of those lists:

```
 public IEnumerable<Produto> GetProdutosIdNotInFamily(Guid produtoId)
        {
            var produtosPai = GetListaPaisId(produtoId);

            var produtosFilho = GetListaFilhosId(produtoId);

            
            var prod = _dbContext.Produtos
                         .Where(u => !produtosPai.Any(p => p.ProdutoFilhoId == u.Id)
                               && !produtosFilho.Any(p => p.ProdutoFilhoId == u.Id));

            return prod;
        }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is the problem you're facing currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways -- One using `Contains` and other using `Any`  like you provided in your snippet in the post.

#### Using `Contains` Method

If you want to use `Contains()` method, you may be pulling out all the product Ids into a collection and apply LINQ on top of it and get the list that is not part of both your reference lists. Sample code is as shown below

```
// This is the sample model I am dealing with
public class Dummy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Assuming the below call returns list of 'Dummy' objects
var products = _dbContext.Produtos;

// list1 & list2 are populated in your case already through the method calls
var exclusionList1 = list1.Select(x => x.Id).ToList<int>();
var exclusionList2 = list2.Select(x => x.Id).ToList<int>();

var myList = products.Where(x => !exclusionList1.Contains(x.Id) && !exclusionList1.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

`Contains` is an instance method and takes an object as a parameter and the time complexity depends on the collection you're using this on.

#### Using `Any`

Just like `Where`, `Any` is an extension method. It takes a delegate as a parameter which gives you greater flexibility and control with respect to what you would want to do.

Applying `Any` to your scenario is as shown below:

```
var products = _dbContext.Produtos;

var exclusionList1 = GetListaPaisId(produtoId);
var exclusionList2 = GetListaFilhosId(produtoId);

var prod = _dbContext.Produtos.Where(x => !exclusionList1.Any(z => x.Id == z.Id) && 
!exclusionList2.Any(z => x.Id == z.Id)).ToList();
```

You can choose your approach based on the context under which you are performing this operation.

Comment: Glad it did! :)